# The sections of the camp of B'nei Yisrael as a reference to the Temple Mount

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, rambam, beis-hamikdash, dor-hamidbar

The Rambam [(Mishneh Torah, Beis HaBechirah, chapter 7, halacha 11)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007200/jewish/Beit-Habechirah-Chapter-7.htm) writes:"

> The [encampment of the Jewish people] in the desert [ was divided into] three areas:
>
> the camp of Israel, which was itself subdivided into four camps;
>
> the camp of the Levites about which [Numbers 1:50] states: "They shall
> camp around the Sanctuary;"
>
> and the camp of the Shechinah [which included the area] beginning at
> the entrance to the courtyard of the Tent of Meeting inwards.

The Rambam goes on to say that these three areas correspond to places in future generations:

> **[The area] from the entrance to Jerusalem to the Temple Mount is comparable to the camp of Israel.**
>
> [The area] from the entrance to the Temple Mount until the entrance to
> the Temple Courtyard, the gate of Nicanor, is comparable to the camp
> of the Levites.
>
> [The area] from the entrance to the Temple Courtyard inward, is
> comparable to the camp of the Shechinah.

Why is the area from the entrance of Jerusalem to the Temple Mount compared to the camp of B'nei Yisrael? (besides the fact that it would lead to the holiest of places ofcourse) Are there sources that explain this?

Comment: Note that it’s not just Jerusalem - any walled city in Israel has the status of “the camp of Israel”, which a Motzora must leave